# How to set a background image on <a> Tag?

Tags: html, css

I need to set a background image on `<a>` tag. for each tag i need a different image. I thought i could simply do something like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeController">
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item" ng-repeat="product in products" href="{{product.templateUrl}}" background="{{product.img}}">
                {{product.name}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

but ofcourse this isnt working.

How can i set a background image on `<a>` tag?

Comment: Maybe just like on a normal div? With background: url("your-image"); ?

Comment: I dont know anything about normal divs. I dont know anything about html and css. That's why im asking :)

Comment: OK. then... you style it simply like style="background: url('your-image')";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply it as inline css on the `a` element.

```
<a ... style="background: url({{product.img}})">
```

Comment: If should display a bit of an image. You'd also probably need `display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px`. If nothing shows then you need to check that the path generated by `{{product.img}}` is correct.

Comment: @Mulgard: I've forgotten the `url(...)`, so probably that fixes it for you.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
.item {
background: url('image.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a 
href="https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/ileetcoder-%E7%88%B1%E5%8A%9B%E6%89%A3/id1458259471?mt=8" 
style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/assets/shared/badges/en-us/appstore-sm.svg) no-repeat;width:60px;height:15px;">
</a>
```