# assign background image from url

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a background image to a  tag, when I set the image link in background-image:url it is not showing me the image as background. This is my code, what could I be doing wrong?

```html
<a
  href="#"
  data-toggle="lightbox"
  title="Instagram"
  style="
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/275180538_484682353010222_2402478995051705385_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s640x640_sh0.08&_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=fTObVsU65g8AX8x2Wuy&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT-oNSMzXpDYHz0_nSlywYBoscNl37e8kWF8dEe3-4zxWA&oe=625818CB&_nc_sid=7bff83') !important;
  "
>
  <div class="photo-box-content">
    <span>Instagram223424</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006018/how-to-set-a-background-image-on-a-tag  This seems to be already answered.

Comment: Check your browser console, most likely it is blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: probably origin issue. You can't just load load something from somewhere else and use it on your website without explicitly allowing

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you are trying to load image from instagram or facebook content because of the URL. It is not allowed to be load like that, try saving the image locally that's the quickest solution.

Comment: right, I'm trying to get images from instagram, a while ago the code worked for me but I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. Is it not being allowed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I will only recommend you to assign the background image locally. First, download the image and then, add it to your code main file. The main problem while you import the url is, if the image of the url is deleted by any reasons, your webpage will not display the image anymore. So, you should download it and then add it to your code main file. Then, rename the picture to a short name (recommended). Then you should code like this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*locally from the device*/
  background: url('example.jpg');
  /*to adjust the image perfectly according to the device*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="body">
      <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the method which I was following for the past few months. Hope it will help you ☺.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same reference with this question, here's the link:

Visit [instagram style explore page image list with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661075/instagram-style-explore-page-image-list-with-css)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted